# Fill empty fields in dataframe from a list of arrays

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am currently working with a dataframe, which I am creating on the fly, basically what I have so far is as follows:

```
  In [2]: df
  Out[2]:
     A  B  C  D
  0  1  
  1  2  
  2  3
```

and I have an array of data arrays in numpy as follows:

`array = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]`

I have tried to fill my dataframe with this data to get the following layout:

```
  In [2]: df
  Out[2]:
     A  B  C  D
  0  1  1  2  3
  1  2  4  5  6
  2  3  7  8  9
```

What I have been trying to do is the following:

`new_df = df.append({k:v for k,v in zip(list_columns,array},  ignore_index=True)`

But I don't get the results I need, I don't have that much experience with pandas, is there an efficient way to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
df[['B', 'C', 'D']] = array
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   A  B  C  D
0  1  1  2  3
1  2  4  5  6
2  3  7  8  9
```

That will work whether the columns were already in the dateframe or not.

Comment: @isaac Did my solution work for you?

Comment: yes it works! Thanks a lot! but what about if I have the columns in a list names, there is other option than put them each one in the df columns names manually? @richardec

Comment: I think you can just do `df[list_columns] = array` in that case.